# Subsetting a data frame by columns and returning a list of those subsets

Tags: r

I want to take a data frame like this one:

```
df <- data.frame(
  SortCol1 = rep(c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four"), times = 5),
  SortCol2 = rep(c("A", "B"), times = 10),
  Arb1 = rep(c(1,0,1,1,0), times = 4),
  Arb2 = rep(c(0,1,1,0,0), times = 4)
)

   SortCol1 SortCol2 Arb1 Arb2
1       One        A    1    0
2       Two        B    0    1
3     Three        A    1    1
4      Four        B    1    0
5       One        A    0    0
6       Two        B    1    0
7     Three        A    0    1
8      Four        B    1    1
9       One        A    1    0
10      Two        B    0    0
11    Three        A    1    0
12     Four        B    0    1
13      One        A    1    1
14      Two        B    1    0
15    Three        A    0    0
16     Four        B    1    0
17      One        A    0    1
18      Two        B    1    1
19    Three        A    1    0
20     Four        B    0    0
```

Then subset it by `SortCol1` and `SortCol2` to return a list of all subsetted data frames.

I have done something similar to this many times before using `ddply` when I want to apply a function to the `Arb1` and `Arb2` columns.

e.g. I know that

```
ddply(df, c("SortCol1", "SortCol2"), numcolwise(sum))
```

Will subset based on the two columns I want, and return a minimal frame which has those columns and the sum function applied.

What I want is rather than applying a function to those columns, just have each subset returned as an element of a list.

Pretend the function that does that is called `ddply_list`. I would hope for something akin to

```
ddply_list(df, c("SortCol1", "SortCol2"))
```

Which would return a list whose elements would be the data frames (which I have manually created for now):

```
df[df$SortCol1=="One" & df$SortCol2 == "A",]
   SortCol1 SortCol2 Arb1 Arb2
1       One        A    1    0
5       One        A    0    0
9       One        A    1    0
13      One        A    1    1
17      One        A    0    1

df[df$SortCol1=="Two" & df$SortCol2 == "B",]
   SortCol1 SortCol2 Arb1 Arb2
2       Two        B    0    1
6       Two        B    1    0
10      Two        B    0    0
14      Two        B    1    0
18      Two        B    1    1
```

etc for all combinations of `SortCol1` and `SortCol2`.

If there's a function list that already, perfect! If not, any advice for how to get towards this solution would be awesome!

The main bit I'm not sure on, is the simplest way to return all subsets of a data frame (subsetted by columns) as a list of data frames.

To put it in another way, the `ddply` documentation described the `.fun` argument as... *function to apply to each piece*. I think what I want is a way of just returning each 'piece' as an element of a list (preferably with the columns used for subsetting still attached).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it's very simple:

```
split(df, df[c("SortCol1", "SortCol2"], drop=TRUE)
```

Answer stolen from here:
[Automatically subset data frame by factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422397/automatically-subset-data-frame-by-factor)

Usage:

```
split(x, f, drop = FALSE, ...)
```

Where `x` is a vector or dataframe and `y` is a factor or list of factors for defining groups.

Comment: Along the right line, but I think you want `split(df, df[1:2], drop=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks! This seems close, but I want to be able to subset based on the unique combinations of SortCol1 and SortCol2. Any ideas?

Comment: @thelatemail, I added that comment before I saw yours. Yours does exactly what I want, thank you! if you want to post it as a solution I'll happily mark it as the answer :)

Comment: I did change it slightly though so I can name the columns, i.e. `df[c("SortCol1", "SortCol2"]`

Comment: I've just edited Amar's answer slightly to account for the change. Everything you need should be there now.

Comment: Ah, I actually didn't know stackoverflow allowed two authors for an answer. Perfect! Thanks :)

Comment: It's probably worth adding the `drop = TRUE` to the answer as well. Though in hindsight I don't think my question was specific about that.